# C++ Sorting Binary Files

Tags: c++, file, sorting, binary

I have a piece of code that won't compile.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int average (int n);

int main() 
{

string filename;

int i,j;
int n = 0;
int sum = 0;
int size = 4;
const int nameLength = 19;
const int maxRecords = 100;
int index[100];


int scores[maxRecords];
char names[maxRecords][nameLength];

int count = 0;

cout << "Enter binary data directory and file name: ";
getline (cin, filename);
// Open file for binary read-write access.
    ifstream fin(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);

if (!fin) {
cout << "Could not open " << filename << endl;
system("PAUSE");
return -1;
}

// Read data from the file.
while (
fin.read(names[count], sizeof(names[0]))
     && fin.read((char *) &scores[count], sizeof(scores[0]))
)
{

    count++;
    fin.ignore(); // skip the padding byte
}


// Display the data and close.
 cout << "Your file's data unsorted: " << endl;
cout << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << "Name" << setw(20) <<  "Test Score" << endl;

    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
            cout << setw(10) << names[i] << setw(20) << scores[i] << endl;
    }

            for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
            index[i]=i;
    }

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {

            for (j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            {
                    int temp;
                    if (scores[index[i]] > scores[index[j]])
                    {
                            temp = index[i];
                            index[i] = index[j];
                            index[j] = temp;
                    }
            }
    }

    cout << "The average of the test scores in your file is:  " << average         (sum);

sum=sum+scores[i];


fin.close();
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

int average (int sum, int size)
{ 
return sum/size;
}
```

I'm getting a compile error that says: `fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals`, and I can't figure out why. Also another question is how do you format it so that the data read from the original binary file does not get tampered and is then outputted and saved in a new edited binary file?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Why exactly is `<windows.h>` included, but not `<cstdlib>`? I don't see anything from the former in here, but `system` is from the latter, not that `system("PAUSE")` is something code should have.

Comment: The Error message says, ""fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals"", and I had <windows.h> in there earlier cause I had a MAX_PATH thing in there that I took out.

Comment: @user2444400, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: @user2444400, And I only ask about `<windows.h>` because it's extremely large. It's a huge set of headers.

Comment: Yeah, since I don't have any use of it I just removed the header. i fixed the compile issue, but now I have an output issue where it just outputs nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You forward declare `average` like so:

```
int average (int n);
```

but you implement average this way:

```
int average (int n, int size);
```

If you update your forward declaration and you add the second argument here:

```
cout << "The average of the test scores in your file is:  " << average(sum,size);
```

that should fix it.

Comment: Alright thanks that fixed it, but now this is my output: Enter binary data directory and file name: C:\Users\Jacky\Desktop\project6.dat
Your file's data unsorted:

      Name          Test Score
The average of the test scores in your file is:  0Press any key to continue . .
.

Comment: Now  you have to fix your program. :)

Comment: Yeah, but could it be with my sorting that's screwing the output up?

Comment: @user2444400 A couple of hints: Read your input loop carefully. Then check the bounds in your output and sorting loops just as carefully. And look at how you're computing the sum.