# How can i sort a binary file?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I have difficulty resolving one sort of simple task. The goal of the task is to combine two binary files into a third, and after the third file, sort in descending order. The resulting file will look something like this:

> 52,sdads
>
> 34,dsad
>
> 98,dasd
>
> 22,asdas

And I have to sort all these lines in descending order by the numbers.
Please at least someone can tell how this can be implemented. What algorithm do I need to solve the problem, or help with what I need to start. I will be very grateful!

```
int main(){

    ofstream ofs("f3", ofstream::binary);
    ifstream ifs;

    ifs.open("f1", ifstream::binary);
    ifs.seekg (0, ifs.end);
    int len = ifs.tellg();
    ifs.seekg (0, ifs.beg);

    char * buffer = new char [len];
    ifs.read(buffer, len);
    ofs.write(buffer, len);
    ifs.close();
    delete[] buffer;

    ifs.open("f2", ifstream::binary);
    ifs.seekg (0, ifs.end);
    len = ifs.tellg();
    ifs.seekg (0, ifs.beg);

    buffer = new char [len];
    ifs.read(buffer, len);
    ofs.write(buffer, len);
    ifs.close();
    delete[] buffer;
}
```

Comment: Did you read this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908671/c-sorting-binary-files Maybe this contains some helpful info

Comment: The title says you want to sort a binary file, the text says it is a text file with lines. So what is the case?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Sorting? Or getting the number from each line? What do you believe should be done and what of this don't you know how to do?

Comment: Use a `struct` or `class` to model a datum.  Create a `std::vector<Datum>`.  Read the file into the vector.  Sort vector.  Write vector to file.

Comment: My problem is to do something like 98, dasd 52, sdads 34, dsad 22, asdas. The file contains data in a column and I need to sort them by numbers from larger to smaller

Comment: Thomas Matthews, okey,thank ty, ill try do something like this

Comment: A binary file does not have the concept of lines.  If its actually a binary file you will have to iterate byte by byte, breaking the datum into pieces based on size or line feed characters.  To me it looks like you have a text file which you can sort using the linux utility sort.  "sort -t, -nk1 mydata.file" will sort your data by number on the first comma separated value if the number is always the first.